# How can I customize the color of error messages in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to customize the Bash error messages attributes?

For example, is it possible to edit the `.bash_profile` to get the following Bash error message

```
-bash: cd: foo: No such file or directory
```

in red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, there is no `PS` prompt variable to control how bash errors are presented.

**stderred** is a comprehensive solution for this type of problem, but it *will not work without modification as it has a hard-coded exclude* for `bash` (read on for good reasons why). Also it's somewhat intrusive (DLL injection).

**hilite** requires you to use it as a wrapper, this won't work for bash builtin commands like `cd`.

Your question asks specifically about bash error messages, these are send to `stderr`, but `stderr` is also shared with any child processes, i.e. any other commands. I'm not sure if you want to distinguish the two.

A hidden issue here is that `bash` itself writes the prompt and your input (echo) to `stderr`. To prove:

```
bash              # start a sacrificial shell
exec 2> tmpfile   # change stderr to a file
ls                # you will see no prompt, and no command echo
... 
exit              # quit sacrificial shell
cat tmpfile       # contains PS1 prompt, your commands (and any errors too)
```

Builtins call (or at least should call) the `builtin_error()` internal function to print errors, this unconditionally calls `fprintf()` to `stderr`, so the options are few.

Without jumping through hoops, or patching `bash`, a simple way of highlighting errors is:

```
function _t_debug() 
{
    if [ "${BASH_COMMAND:0:6}" != "_t_err" ]; then
        _lastcmd="$BASH_COMMAND"
    fi  
}
function _t_err() 
{
    local rc=$1 nn _type _argv
    #shift; pipe=($*)
    #if [ ${#pipe[*]} -gt 1 ]; then
    #    for ((nn=1; nn<=${#pipe[*]};nn++));do
    #        rc=${pipe[$((nn-1))]}
    #        echo -n "[$nn]=$rc ";
    #        ((rc >=128)) && echo -n "($((rc-128))) "
    #    done
    #fi

    read -a _argv <<< ${_lastcmd}
    _type=$(type -t "${_argv[0]}")

    if [ -n "$_lastcmd" ]; then
        tput setf 4
        printf 'Error %s: "%s"' "${_type}" "${_lastcmd:-unknown command}"
        tput sgr 0
        printf "\n"
    fi

    ((rc >=128)) && echo "[rc=$rc ($((rc-128)))]" ||
    echo "[rc=$rc]"
}
trap '_t_err $? ${PIPESTATUS[*]}' ERR
trap '_t_debug' DEBUG
```

This uses the bash `DEBUG` trap to cache each command line before execution, and the `ERR` trap to output the return codes if non-zero. This won't though for certain bash builtins (specifically *compound commands*: `while/case/for/if` and more, see man page).

I use a variation on this in my `.profile`, though I use the `pipe[]/PIPESTATUS[]` bit commented out above, it's not compatible with a DEBUG trap as presented above. If you comment out the `trap DEBUG` then you can use it to show the return code of each command in a pipeline.

(Also, since it's referenced, the `command_not_found` function hook is bash-4.0+.)

Answer (score 2):

Below solution works for what you want:

```
# whatever_command 2> >(while read line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done)
```

Basically, above command prints **stderr** in red.

Check below screen shot:

[image]

I do not know how to make this permanent. However, this should definitely give you some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [stderrred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) for a more permanent sollution.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file for a permanent fix, or, if you want it to be temporary, just type this into `bash`.

```
command_not_found_handle () { 
  tput bold;
  tput setaf 1;
  echo "$0: $1: command not found"; 
  tput sgr0; 
}
```

It will make `bash` output the command not found error in bold, and red.  Go ahead and take out `tput bold;` to make it so that the error message is not bold, or change the `tput setaf 1` to another number for a different color.  Hope it helps!!

**EDIT**

Here is a new and improved version of the above:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
  echo -e "\e[1;31m$0: $1: command not found\e[0;0m";
  return 127; #return bash's error code for command not found
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, bash
searches each element of the PATH for a directory containing an executable file by that
name. Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files (see hash
under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below). A full search of the directories in PATH is performed
only if the command is not found in the hash table. If the search is unsuccessful, the
shell searches for a defined shell function named command_not_found_handle. If that
function exists, it is invoked with the original command and the original command's
arguments as its arguments, and the function's exit status becomes the exit status of the
shell. If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error message and returns an
exit status of 127.
```

Taken from [bash's manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

So if this does not work, maybe your shell is not true `bash`, or it is a modified version of `bash`.

Comment: Thanks BenjiWiebe, your solution seems very interesting, but unfortunately, it doesn't work, even a more simple solution, like `command_not_found_handle () { echo "Error..." }`: I still get the basic `-bash: foo: command not found`? I'm using a Mac OSX operating system.

Comment: @Hassinus Are you really using `bash`? See edit 2

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Your solution only traps one specific error, a failure in command lookups. The example in the question is not such an error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [hilite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hilite/) - I think this is one of most simple solutions.